# Reusing a Polly retrial policy for multiple Refit endpoints without explicitly managing the HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dry, polly, refit

I am trying to make Refit work with Polly in an ASP.NET Core 6 application. I have a working version, but I feel that there is too much code involved for each new method / consumed API endpoint.

I want to keep things simple for now by defining a retrial policy and using it for multiple endpoints. My code is as follows:

#### The retrial policy

```cs
private static IServiceCollection ConfigureResilience(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var retryPolicy = Policy<IApiResponse>
        .Handle<ApiException>()
        .OrResult(x => x.StatusCode is >= HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError or HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), RetryPolicyMaxCount));

    var register = new PolicyRegistry()
    {
        { "DefaultRetrialPolicy", retryPolicy }
    };

    services.AddPolicyRegistry(register);

    return services;
}
```

#### The interface to be used with Refit to generate the HTTP calls for the external application:

```cs
[Headers("Authorization: Bearer")]
public interface IBarIntegration
{
    [Get("/api/ext/Foo/GetFooBriefInfo")]
    Task<ApiResponse<GetFooBriefInfoForFooDto>> GetFooBriefInfo(GetFooBriefInfoForFooInputDto inputData);
}
```

#### Factory class to configure authentication for Refit. Authentication relies OnBehalfOf token generated based on the currently logged-in user access token.

```cs
internal sealed class BarApiClientHelper : IBarApiClientHelper
{
    private readonly IOptionsSnapshot<BarApiSettings> _BarSettings;
    private readonly IAccessTokenHelperService _accessTokenHelperService;

    public BarApiClientHelper(IOptionsSnapshot<BarApiSettings> BarSettings, IAccessTokenHelperService accessTokenHelperService)
    {
        _BarSettings = BarSettings;
        _accessTokenHelperService = accessTokenHelperService;
    }

    public async Task<TApiClient> CreateApiClient<TApiClient>(CancellationToken token)
    {
        string baseUrl = _BarSettings.Value.BaseUrl;
        string accessToken = await _accessTokenHelperService.GetAccessToken(token);

        var refitClient = RestService.For<TApiClient>(baseUrl, new RefitSettings
        {
            AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = () => Task.FromResult(accessToken)
        });

        return refitClient;
    }
}
```

#### Example (infrastructure) method that will be called by the business layer.

```cs
public async Task<GetFooBriefInfoForFooDto> GetFooBriefInfo(string upn, CancellationToken token)
{
    var apiClient = await _clientHelper.CreateApiClient<IBarIntegration>(token);
    var retrialPolicy = _registry.Get<AsyncRetryPolicy<IApiResponse>>(DefaultRetrialPolicy);

    var func = async () => (IApiResponse) await apiClient.GetFooBriefInfo(new GetFooBriefInfoForFooInputDto { FooContactUpn = upn });
    var FooInfo = (ApiResponse<GetFooBriefInfoForFooDto>) await retrialPolicy.ExecuteAsync(func);
    await FooInfo.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync();

    return FooInfo.Content!;
}
```

This approach seems to work fine, but I am unhappy with the amount of code required in each business-specific method (GetFooBriefInfo function). Is there any way to simplify this, I feel that I am kind of violating DRY by having each method get the retrial policy, executing and ensuring the success code.

Comment: Do you want to have a refit client which is already decorated with polly policy inside your `GetFooBriefInfo` method, so you don't have to explicitly call the `ExecuteAsync`? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I've never used Refit, but a quick glance suggests that it's compatible with HttpClientFactory, and Polly is also compatible with HttpClientFactory and would give you a more centralised location to configure retry policy. Is this something that you can use?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama You can chain [`AddRefitClient`](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/0baec2ea6f462264696fe476a88dfc267b527ad7/Refit.HttpClientFactory/HttpClientFactoryExtensions.cs) with `AddPolicyHandler`, so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refit defines an extension method against `IServiceCollection` called [`AddRefitClient`](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/0baec2ea6f462264696fe476a88dfc267b527ad7/Refit.HttpClientFactory/HttpClientFactoryExtensions.cs) which returns an `IHttpClientBuilder`. This is good for us, since it is the same interface with which the `AddHttpClient` extension method returns. So, we can use the `AddPolicyHandler`, `AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy` or `AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry` methods as well.

### Refit client + Polly policy

Because we can chain the `AddRefitClient`, `ConfigureHttpClient` and `AddPolicyHandler` method calls that's why we can

- avoid the usage of the `PolicyRegistry`
- avoid the usage of the `BarApiClientHelper`
- avoid the explicit usage of the policy itself

#### Registration

```
services
.AddRefitClient(typeof(IBarIntegration), (sp) =>
{
    var accessTokenHelperService = sp.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenHelperService>();
    string accessToken = accessTokenHelperService.GetAccessToken(CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return new RefitSettings
    {
        AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = () => Task.FromResult(accessToken)
    };
})
.ConfigureHttpClient((sp, client) =>
{
    var barSettings = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<BarApiSettings>>();
    string baseUrl = barSettings.Value.BaseUrl;
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
})
.AddPolicyHandler(Policy<IApiResponse>
    .Handle<ApiException>()
    .OrResult(x => x.StatusCode is >= HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError or HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), RetryPolicyMaxCount)));
```

- The `AddRefitClient` receives a Type, which is used to register a typed client

  - It also anticipates a `settingsAction` function to setup a `RefitSettings`

    - Unfortunately this delegate is sync that's why I had to use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `await`
    - I've passed a `CancellationToken.None` to the `GetAccessToken`, because here we don't want to cancel this call
- The `ConfigureHttpClient` is used to set the `BaseAddress` for the underlying `HttpClient` which will be used by the refit client
- The `AddPolicyHandler` is used to set the resilience policy for the refit client

#### Usage

```
private readonly IBarIntegration apiClient; //injected via ctor
public async Task<GetFooBriefInfoForFooDto> GetFooBriefInfo(string upn, CancellationToken token)
{
    var fooInfo = await apiClient.GetFooBriefInfo(new GetFooBriefInfoForFooInputDto { FooContactUpn = upn });
    await fooInfo.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync();
    return fooInfo.Content!;
}
```

- There is no need to use the `IBarApiClientHelper` because the `IBarIntegration` can be injected directly
- There is no need to retrieve the Polly policy and manually decorate the `GetFooBriefInfo` method call, because we have already integrated the refit client and the policy during the DI registration

---

**UPDATE #1**
Based on the suggestion of [Can Bilgin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5592556/can-bilgin) the registration code could be rewritten like this:

```
services
.AddRefitClient(typeof(IBarIntegration), (sp) =>
{
    var accessTokenHelperService = sp.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenHelperService>();
    return new RefitSettings
    {
        AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = async () => await accessTokenHelperService.GetAccessToken(CancellationToken.None)
    };

})
.ConfigureHttpClient((sp, client) =>
{
    var barSettings = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<BarApiSettings>>();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(barSettings.Value.BaseUrl);
})
...
```

Comment: just a question here, wouldn't you be able to pass `accessTokenHelperService.GetAccessToken(CancellationToken.None)` as the `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter` cause we are awaiting the result and then passing it into a Task.FromResult. It could make the code and execution simpler.

Comment: @CanBilgin You are right. Thanks for the tip. Let me amend my post.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you for taking the time for a full answer. I have managed to make this work with minor changes. AFAIK, this is the single resource that includes Refit, Polly, and configuring the authentication in an elegant way.

Comment: @Alexei-checkCodidact I'm glad to read that it helped you solving the problem. :) Have a great day mate!

Comment: In order for policy to get exwecuted, the PolicyHandler should be configured before the HttpClient, so the correct sequence would be `services.AddRefitClient(...).AddPolicyHandler(...).ConfigureHttpClient(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Peter's great answer the infrastructure code looks as follows:

```cs
private static IServiceCollection ConfigureResilience(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddRefitClient(typeof(IBarIntegration), (sp) =>
        {
            var accessTokenHelperService = sp.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenHelperService>();
            return new RefitSettings
            {
                AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = () => accessTokenHelperService.GetAccessToken(default)
            };
        })
        .ConfigureHttpClient((sp, client) =>
        {
            var BarSettings = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BarApiSettings>>();
            string baseUrl = BarSettings.Value.BaseUrl;
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        })
        .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(policyBuilder =>
            policyBuilder.WaitAndRetryAsync(    Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), RetryPolicyMaxCount)
            )
        );
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), RetryPolicyMaxCount)));

    return services;
}
```

I have made some changes and I will clarify them below (I am not sure how good are some of them):

1. `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = () => accessTokenHelperService.GetAccessToken(default)` is more direct (or perhaps safer than using `.Result`. However, this means that this will be called for each HTTP call and getting the access token should use some cache. In my case, I am using OBO which adds ~400ms for each call, so using a cache is a must.

In this case, I am not sure if this change is OK from a token acquisition perspective (I guess it is a better choice in the async..await world).

2. Policy handler has to deal with `HttpResponseMessage` and `HttpRequestException` since Polly is applied to the `HttpClient`.

The actual Refit interface has been simplified to:

```cs
[Headers("Authorization: Bearer")]
public interface IBarIntegration
{
    [Get("/api/ext/Foo/GetFooBriefInfo")]
    Task<GetFooBriefInfoForFooDto> GetFooBriefInfo(GetFooBriefInfoForFooInputDto inputData);
}
```

`IBarIntegration` can be directly injected now. The only thing I dislike a little is that I had to reference Refit in the "Application" layer (the solution is a "Clean architecture"), but I like simplicity over yet another abstraction.

Comment: You could simplify your retry policy by using HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError or by registering a simple retry via AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy call instead of AddPolicyHandler